# Merge With Wild Cards

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas data frames using multiple columns with wild card characters.

Consider data sets, where result is the result of the desired merge:

```
left=pd.DataFrame({'Type':['ABC','ADEC','OOO','DOG','MOT'], 'ID':[22,44,23,21,55]})
right=pd.DataFrame({'Type':['ABC','ADE*','*','DOG'], 'ID':[22,'*','23','2*'], 'Value': [0,1,1,0]})
result=pd.DataFrame({'Type':['ABC','ADEC','OOO','DOG','MOT'], 'ID':[22,44,23,21,55],'Value': [0,1,1,0,'NaN']})
```

Which Gives:

```
left
   ID  Type
0  22   ABC
1  44  ADEC
2  23   OOO  
3  21   DOG
4  55   MOT

right
   ID  Type  Value
0  22   ABC      0
1   *  ADE*      1
2  23     *      1
3  2*   DOG      0

result
   ID  Type Value
0  22   ABC     0
1  44  ADEC     1
2  23   OOO     1
3  21   DOG     0
4  55   MOT   NaN
```

I tried to accomplish this using:

```
pd.merge(left=left, right=right, left_on=['Type', 'ID'], right_on ['Type','ID'], how='left')
```

But ended up with:

```
pd.merge(left=left, right=right, left_on=['Type', 'ID'], right_on= ['Type','ID'], how='left')
   ID  Type  Value
0  22   ABC    0.0
1  44  ADEC    NaN
2  23   OOO    NaN
3  21   DOG    NaN
4  55   MOT    NaN
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Pandas has the functionality of using wildcards in merge, joins, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Type': ['ABC', 'ADEC', 'OOO', 'DOG', 'MOT'], 'ID': [22, 44, 23, 21, 55]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['ABC', 'ADE*', '*', 'DOG'],
                      'ID': [22, '*', '23', '2*'], 'Value': [0, 1, 1, 0]},
                     index=list('ABCD'))
expected = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['ABC', 'ADEC', 'OOO', 'DOG', 'MOT'], 'ID': [
                      22, 44, 23, 21, 55], 'Value': [0, 1, 1, 0, 'NaN']})

data = {}
for col in ['ID', 'Type']:
    right[col] = right[col].astype(str).str.replace('*','.')
    left[col] = left[col].astype(str)
    data[col] = (right[col].apply(lambda pat: left.loc[left[col].str.match(pat), col])
                 .stack().to_frame(col))
    data[col].index = data[col].index.droplevel(level=1)

expanded = (data['ID']
            .join(data['Type'])
            .join(right['Value']))

result = pd.merge(left, expanded, how='left')


print(result)
```

yields

```
   ID  Type  Value
0  22   ABC    0.0
1  44  ADEC    1.0
2  23   OOO    1.0
3  21   DOG    0.0
4  55   MOT    NaN
```

---

If you change the `*` to `.`, you could regard the values in `right` as regex patterns.
Then you could use `str.match(pat)` to test if patterns in `right` match strings in `left`. For example,

```
In [297]: right
Out[297]: 
   ID  Type  Value
A  22   ABC      0
B   .  ADE.      1
C  23     .      1
D  2.   DOG      0

In [298]: left
Out[298]: 
   ID  Type
0  22   ABC
1  44  ADEC
2  23   OOO
3  21   DOG
4  55   MOT

In [271]: right['ID'].apply(lambda pat: left.loc[left['ID'].str.match(pat), 'ID'])
Out[271]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
A   22  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
B   22   44   23   21   55
C  NaN  NaN   23  NaN  NaN
D   22  NaN   23   21  NaN
```

This DataFrame shows for each row of `right` what values in `left['ID']` match the pattern. For example,  in the last row, the pattern is `2.` which matches `22`, `23` and `21` in `left['ID']`.

If we `stack` this DataFrame, we get a Series listing all the possible expansions of the wildcard character:

```
In [299]: right['ID'].apply(lambda pat: left.loc[left['ID'].str.match(pat), 'ID']).stack()
Out[299]: 
A  0    22
B  0    22
   1    44
   2    23
   3    21
   4    55
C  2    23
D  0    22
   2    23
   3    21
dtype: object
```

The same can be done for `Type`. Join the two results together to obtain a DataFrame which lists every valid expansion of the wildcard characters:

```
In [301]: expanded = (data['ID']
                      .join(data['Type'])
                      .join(right['Value']))
Out[301]: 
   ID  Type  Value
A  22   ABC      0
B  22  ADEC      1
B  44  ADEC      1
B  23  ADEC      1
B  21  ADEC      1
B  55  ADEC      1
C  23   ABC      1
C  23  ADEC      1
C  23   OOO      1
C  23   DOG      1
C  23   MOT      1
D  22   DOG      0
D  23   DOG      0
D  21   DOG      0
```

Now the desired result can be obtained by a left-merge of `left` and `expanded`:

```
result = pd.merge(left, expanded, how='left')
```

---

PS: I altered `right` to have `index=list('ABCD')` instead of the usual
`[0,1,2,3]` so that the index values on `left` and `right` do not happen to
align with the way we want the rows to match. I did this to guard against developing an solution that mistakenly takes advantage of this
coincidence.